# How can I automatically do tasks online with a service in .Net platform?

Tags: winforms, web-services, asp.net-web-api, service

I have a C# winforms app that scrapes data from web.

What I would like to do is to do the scraping task online and I would like it to run automatically in every one hour so that when the users open the winforms app the data is always updated.

How can I achieve this? What should I use?

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning on building your server on .NET technology then I'd recommend ASP.NET Core Web API.

Actually, you have two options Web API or WCF. WCF is easy to integrate with .net but Web API is better in other aspects.

ASP.NET Core Web APIs are very easy to build and they are RESTful so, you could get data with HTTP requests.

You could use Hangfire to achieve this.

Hangfire can perform CRON tasks with minimal configuration plus if the server goes down it does not flush all the tasks because it stores task info. in database.

I've used it in my Web API for syncing with Google API every day.

Refer [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) for more info.